# Developing for AXIS IP camera systems

Tags: sdk, programming-languages, ip-camera

I would like to write some applications involving IP cameras. AXIS has a greatoverview on their pages. They provide API for their cameras called Vapix and they also indroduce Open Platform SDK, which is supposed to be some form of SDK that enables developers to write code specifically for the devices. E.g. communication with server over your own protocol.

The problem is - they require registration and an entrance fee to enroll in the developer program. My question is, though, **WHICH** language do they support? Is it C, Java?

Note: I am not talking about the Vapix API, I am talking about the Open Platform SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is written in C/C++. Note that they have their own compiler based on GNU Linux.